# VBA Save as runtime error 1004

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error

I have written this VBA code to save a new version of a file in a specified location. It works absolutely fine on my computer but won't work on a colleagues. We are both using the same version of Excel. I have made sure there are no passwords in the workbook and also made sure he has full permissions on the file.

```
Sub SaveNew()

Dim FileName As String
Dim Path As String
Dim Plnt As String
Dim PC As String
Dim fso As FileSystemObject

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")


'Save and calculate workbook before changes. Patse Filename so it doesnt change

ActiveWorkbook.Save
ActiveSheet.Calculate
ActiveSheet.Select
Range("c7").Copy
Range("c8").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

'Define path and filename

Path = "Z:\UK\BFD\MAReports$\PPV & MR21\Stock Loss\Site Files\"
FileName = Sheets("Menu").Range("c8")
Plnt = Sheets("Menu").Range("c3")
PC = Sheets("Menu").Range("c5")


'Save new version

ThisWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=Path & FileName & ".xlsm", FileFormat:=52
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: does the code stop at a specific line on your colleague's computer ?

Comment: Yes it does sorry. It stops on the below line.

Comment: ThisWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=Path & FileName & ".xlsm", FileFormat:=52

Comment: Probably the path is specific to the user. Can he have access to this folder ?

Comment: The error message is:
Microsoft Excel cannot access the file 'xxxx/xxxx/xxxx/xxxx' there are several possible reasons. The file name or path doesn't exist, the file is being used by another program, the workbook you are trying to save has the same name as a...

It look slike its trying to save it as a temp file name ("96314000")

Comment: Yes its a shared folder on a network drive that we often use

Comment: and the path to this folder is exactly the same on his computer ? Like it doesn't depend on the user for sure ?

Comment: I'll navigate to the folder on his computer and see if its the same. Although I imagine it would be

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of things that are odd about this code, see comments to the right:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Save 'saves the current book (that's ok)
ActiveSheet.Calculate 'only meaningful if you have calculation set to manual
ActiveSheet.Select 'why select the activesheet, you're not using the selection
Range("c7").Copy 'why copy/paste c7 to c8? if c7 is empty the saveAs fails
Range("c8").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues 'this is better: Range("c8").Value = Range("c7").Value
```

And probably the problem you have is either caused by:

1- SaveAs does not save a copy but saves the current workbook under a new name so if another user on another computer runs the same macro and Z: is a shared drive then the other user/computer will have the same file locked that you want to save to until on the other computer Excel is closed and the other user/computer and you/your computer have the same privileges on this file.

2- You/your computer has no authorization to write on that network location

I've tested your code and I can replicate cause 1 with the same 1004 runtime error